# Medical Image Analysis

Tags: image-classification, image-recognition, image-preprocessing

What are some good starting points for learning medical image analysis and combining it with deep learning?

I would like to analyze images with bone cancers but not sure what is proper way to preprocess them and prepare for the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [blog post](https://dida.do/blog/pattern-recognition-in-medical-imaging). There you find a summary of two fairly new papers from the field, which might start you off. One about semantic segmentation, the other about a classification problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the brand new "[AI for Medical Diagnosis](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ai-for-medical-diagnosis)" course on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ai-for-medical-diagnosis). In this course, you will learn how to apply Machine Learning (ML) techniques to concrete problems in modern medicine. Moreover, it focuses on several medical imaging problems. You can also look at some of our works [1, 2, 3], where we introduce these topics across the breast cancer diagnosis. Finally, we have some interesting and easy sample of [some tools](https://medium.com/oppr/using-cornerstonejs-and-orthanc-to-support-deep-learning-projects-c9675819c33a) for medical imaging analysis.

## References

[1] Francisco M. Calisto, Alfredo Ferreira, Jacinto C. Nascimento, and Daniel Gonçalves. 2017. Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation. In Proceedings of the 2017 ACM International Conference on Interactive Surfaces and Spaces (ISS '17). Association for Computing Machinery, New York, NY, USA, 390–395. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/3132272.3134111

[2] Francisco Maria Calisto, Nuno Nunes, and Jacinto C. Nascimento. 2020. BreastScreening: On the Use of Multi-Modality in Medical Imaging Diagnosis. In Proceedings of the International Conference on Advanced Visual Interfaces (AVI '20). Association for Computing Machinery, New York, NY, USA, Article 49, 1–5. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/3399715.3399744

[3] Francisco Maria Calisto, Carlos Santiago, Nuno Nunes, Jacinto C. Nascimento, Introduction of human-centric AI assistant to aid radiologists for multimodal breast image classification, International Journal of Human-Computer Studies, Volume 150, 2021, 102607, ISSN 1071-5819, DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijhcs.2021.102607

Comment: Thank you so much for helpful references.